# Changing the size of my UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that I would like to change the size of frame. It seems that no matter how small I want it there is set minimum size that I can't go smaller than. I have seen other posts about this but they are very old and the code is much different now. I know how to adjust the height and width of the rows in the picker view but not the frame itself. Even in the **Frame Inspector** no matter what I change on the height and width it will not go smaller than a certain size.

Comment: Read the first line "I would like to change the size of the frame" @matt

Comment: why so aggressive matt if you cant add anything to the post get out at least Tobias made a suggestion unlike your toxic attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the size of a UIPickerView without doing strange hacks. The class is written for specific dimensions and if you do hack it to change the size it leads to weird issues.

I would suggest you use the [iCarousel library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) to implement a custom picker view.