# UIPickerView automatic dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

For dynamic row heights in `UITableView` Swift has

```
UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Is there an equivalent for `UIPickerView`

Comment: If I´m not mistaking I don´t think this is available for a `UIPickerView`

Comment: You can't do this with `UIPickerView`.  [Try using a third party library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386005/changing-the-size-of-my-uipickerview-in-swift).

Answer (score -1):

You may try to get the number of characters of your pickerView Row String and duplicate it by some number of pixels in order to get a decent row width that will fit dynamically to your content.
I had to do that when displaying live prices and made something like that:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let charcterWidth = 20
    let priceComponentWidth = CGFloat((self.lastPrice?.formatStringWithCommasOnly().count ?? 0) * charcterWidth)
    return priceComponentWidth
}
```